# Format error for exec() / Qu'est-ce que : Erreur de format pour exec()

Tags: terminal

I'm running Kali Linux 20.04. In a course at school the teacher asked us to install hadoop. I followed the installation procedure https://tecadmin.net/install-hadoop-on-ubuntu-20-04/ After executing this command `hdfs namenode -format`, I get the following error:

`/home/hadoop/hadoop-3.3.0/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 1812: /opt/jdk1.8.0_291/bin/java: impossible to execute the binary file: Format error for exec()`

`/home/hadoop/hadoop-3.3.0/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 1812: /opt/jdk1.8.0_291/bin/java: Success`

To tell the truth I really don't know what to do. I have searched on several platforms but no success. I hope you can help me.

---

Bonjour !!! Je suis sous Kali Linux 20.04.
Et dans le cadre d'un cours à l'école le prof nous as demandé d'installé hadoop.
j'ai suivie la procédure d'installation https://tecadmin.net/install-hadoop-on-ubuntu-20-04/
Après exécution de cette commande `hdfs namenode -format`,
j'obtient l'erreur suivante:
`/home/hadoop/hadoop-3.3.0/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: ligne 1812: /opt/jdk1.8.0_291/bin/java : impossible d'exécuter le fichier binaire : Erreur de format pour exec()`

`/home/hadoop/hadoop-3.3.0/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: ligne 1812: /opt/jdk1.8.0_291/bin/java: Succès`

A vrai dire je ne sais vraiment pas quoi faire.
J'ai cherché sur plusieurs plateformes mais aucun succès.
J’espère que vous pourriez me venir en aide.

Comment: I'd run `file` on the java file and would try executing it from the command line. I'd also look into that shell script and find out why line 1812 causes an error, but returns success.

Comment: Does it actually give those _both_ "errors" from the same run, and for the same line? That seems really odd, especially since "errors" that give the message "Success" are not that common, IMO. If you can, show what the script contains on that lines. And maybe the surrounding ones. Something like `cat -n hadoop-functions.sh | sed -ne '1810,1814` maybe, to get the line numbers too.

Comment: Also, good job translating the error messages. For someone who mostly speaks just English with a computer, error messages in other languages can be a bit confusing at times... I think the exact English error Bash gives for that situation (and it looks like a message from Bash) is: "...: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error"

Comment: @DragoneTiger a trick when posting messages with errors, is to do first `export LANG=C` or `export LANG=C.UTF-8` that way no translation happens (and it defaults to binary's native which is almost always English).

Comment: @A.B. I prefer `LANG=C failingCommand`, which only affects `failingCommand`, and leaves everything else in Klingon or whatever.